# SPO model via StMoMo

Tags: r

I would like to create the SPO model with the StMoMO package but I have the following error that elqun can help me please. the error is mainly at the level of the declaration of the f4 function I think

code :

```
f2 <- function(x, ages) mean(ages) - x

f3 <- function(x, ages) (pmax((mean(ages) - x) ,0))

f4 <- function(x, ages = 40) {
       n1 = ((pmax((ages - x) ,0))) 
       n2 = (-0.584 * ((pmax((x - ages) ,0)))) 
       n3 = n1 + n2
}       


constSPO <- function(ax, bx, kt, b0x, gc, wxt, ages) {
       
           nYears <- dim(wxt)[2]

        x <- ages

        t <- 1:nYears

        c <- (1 - tail(ages, 1)):(nYears - ages[1])

        xbar <- mean(x)

        #nsum g(c)=0, nsum cg(c)=0, nsum c^2g(c)=0
        phiReg <- lm(gc ~ 1 + c + I(c^2), na.action = na.omit)
        phi <- coef(phiReg)
        gc <- gc - phi[1] - phi[2] * c - phi[3] * c^2
        kt[2, ] <- kt[2, ] + 2 * phi[3] * t
        kt[1, ] <- kt[1, ] + phi[2] * t + phi[3] * (t^2 - 2 * xbar * t)
        ax <- ax + phi[1] - phi[2] * x + phi[3] * x^2
        #nsum kt[i, ] = 0
        ci <- rowMeans(kt, na.rm = TRUE)
        ax <- ax + ci[1] + ci[2] * (xbar - x) + ci[3] *  ((pmax(xbar - x, 0))) 
        kt[1, ] <- kt[1, ] - ci[1]
        kt[2, ] <- kt[2, ] - ci[2]
        kt[3, ] <- kt[3, ] - ci[3]
        kt[4, ] <- kt[4, ] - ci[4] 
        list(ax = ax, bx = bx, kt = kt, b0x = b0x, gc = gc)
}
SPO <- StMoMo(link = "log", staticAgeFun = TRUE,
              periodAgeFun = c("1", f2,f3,f4), cohortAgeFun = "1",
              constFun = constSPO)

FRAmale <- StMoMoData(FRAdata, series = "male")
FRAfemale <- StMoMoData(FRAdata, series = "female")
ages.fit <- 0:100
years.fit <- 1950:2018

SPOfit <- fit(SPO, data = FRAmale, ages.fit = ages.fit,
              years.fit = years.fit)


ERROR : 

Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "B__", value = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  : 
  replacement has 101 rows, data has 6969
```

le modèle :

l (,) =  + () + (̅ − )() + (̅ − )^+ ()+ [( − )^+ + ( − )+]^ () + − + ,t